# Creating two identical looking TabItems but with different bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm workin on a program, which offers a easy to use interface to edit config-files. The config-files contain two sections which are loadeded into two different lists.[image: MainWindow]

Now the two lists should visually appear the same(like above), without replicating the code if possible, so that I dont have the same code twice and only the binding differs. I'm working with the MVVM-Pattern and thats the XAML-Code for the TabItem:

```
<TabItem Header="Windows">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Kreditoren Software"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="135,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Label.Content>
                        <Binding Path="CfgVersion"/>
                    </Label.Content>
                    <Label.ContentStringFormat>
                        File-Version: {0}
                    </Label.ContentStringFormat>
                </Label>

                <Border Background="{StaticResource BrushC1}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushC6}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentControl 
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Content="" 
                            Foreground="{StaticResource BrushC7}"
                            Effect="{StaticResource ShadowS11}"
                            Margin="0" 
                            Style="{StaticResource ico_search}"
                            Height="{StaticResource IconHeight}"
                            Width="{StaticResource IconWidth}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            IsTabStop="False" 
                            TabIndex="-1"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,4" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ListView x:Name="Kred_ListView" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,5" ItemsSource="{Binding Kreditoren, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKreditor, Mode=TwoWay}" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseClick">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="behavior:ListViewBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.IsListEditable}" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="true"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="behavior:ListViewBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock>
                                                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveKreditorCommand}">
                                                            <Image Grid.Column="0"  Height="20" Source="/S-Param;component/Resources/delete.png" Margin="5,0"/>
                                                        </Hyperlink>
                                                    </TextBlock>

                                                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                                        <TextBox Height="18" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="Bearbeiten" Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible}" Margin="100,0,10,0" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="Speichern" Visibility="{Binding IsEditButtonVisible}" Margin="0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="Übernehmen" Visibility="{Binding IsSaveListButtonVisible}" Margin="0" Command="{Binding SaveListCommand}"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="Neu..." Visibility="{Binding IsSaveListButtonVisible}" Margin="100,0,10,0" Command="{Binding AddKreditorCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

If further Information is required I'll try to append them.

If there are grammar or spelling errors, feel free to correct them.

Comment: DataTemplates and a TemplateSelector are your friend

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataTemplates and from what I've just read, wouldn't there be the same code twice?

Comment: A TabControl is an ItemsControl. Lets say you have a collection with config files you can just assign that collection to your TabControl's ItemSource. Then you just need to define an ItemTemplate. Same visual for all items but different data.

Comment: What about using `Style` for your `TabItem` and setting it's `Template` property with the `Grid` that you defined, it should be identical then. HTH

Comment: @XAMIMAX And how would i manage the different bindings?